# multi line variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this javascript variable with some data from an array , but i cant figure out the right syntax to make this work..

```
certifications will be "Win7,Win8,PDI"

var myArray = certifications.split(",");

var data = "[{" +
        for (var i in myArray)
        " "id":i,"text":myArray[i]}, " +
        "}]";
```

I'm hoping to get my data variable to look something like:

```
var data = "[{"id":0,"text":Win7},{"id":1,"text":Win8},{"id":2,"text":PDI}]";
```

Comment: Don't try to create object literal strings. Just create real objects!

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why would you? If you want to create JSON strings, use `JSON.stringify()` on real objects and arrays.

Comment: your right. thanks bergi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(certifications.split(",").map(function(value, index) {
    return {
        id: index,
        text: value
    };
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe += is what your looking for:

```
var certifications = "Win7,Win8,PDI";
var myArray = certifications.split(",");
var data = "[{";

for (var i in myArray) {
    data += " " +
    "id" +":"+i+","+
    "text" + ":"+myArray[i]+"}, ";
}
data += "}]";
```

Comment: Yes, that might work, but you need to ensure that `i` and `myArray[i]` are properly escaped

Comment: @friedi has a much better solution. Hopefully he uses that instead of making his own JSON.